# Moving hard drive to another laptop. (similar model)

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, bootcamp, partition, windows

I am trying to take the hard drive from a Macbook Pro 13-inch Mid 2012 (Model Identifier: MacBookPro9,2) and put this hard drive into a Macbook Pro 13-inch Early 2011 (Model Identifier: MacBookPro8,1). The hard drive is partitioned, one partition is osx, and one partition is windows 7 64bit. When I put this hard drive into the Macbook Pro 13-inch Early 2011, the osx partition works, but the windows partition for some reason does not work. Basically, it will load, and quickly go into a blue screen and then restart. If anyone can give me some advice on this, that would be great. Thanks

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question!

Comment: You may need a Windows expert to fix this, but as to the background - Macs have long been capable of swapping drives to dissimilar hardware & still being capable of booting & running as normal [so long as the new machine is capable of running that OS version]. That's because all drivers are already there. Windows on the other hand only carries the subset of drivers necessary to run on one particular hardware config. Moving it can result in what you are seeing. The 'fix' is to be able to 'inject' the correct drivers to it. That's the bit I can't answer, sorry.